# RewriteRule not working in .htaccess nor apache2.conf

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting mad on what probably is a simple problem.

I need to rewrite all the urls like this:

http://stage.mydomain.com/post/F9YxPF/my_post_title
to 
http://stage.mydomain.com/post.php?uid_url=F9YxPF

The .htaccess is processed properly, when I set basic rules it's working but when I try build a rewriterule to match that structure I always get a 404.

Any help will be hugely appreciated!

Edit: my original RewriteRule was:

RewriteRule ^/?post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(\?.*)?$ /post.php?uid_url=$1 [L]

Comment: Well, we certainly cannot help you  if you do not post that rule you have issue with!

Comment: Yo're right, the one that I was using was this one: RewriteRule ^/?post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(\?.*)?$ /post.php?uid_url=$1 [L]

Comment: A general note: please _always_ include additional information directly into the question itself. Technical details in comments are very hard to read. There is an `edit` button below the question for that. The issue at hand is the `\?` inside your matching pattern. A literal question mark cannot be part of a URL, so the rule will never match. Since you are not interested in what comes behind the `uid` you can safely ignore it. Just as I showed in my answer below.

Comment: Done! Thanks again for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough guess would be this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?post/([^/]+)/? /post.php?uid_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `[^/]` pattern certainly could be defined more specific, you would need to provide a clear definition what characters should be accepted as uid's.

But as said above in the comments: it really would make sense for you to post the rule you are currently trying which is faulty. Otherwise this is only *guess work*... Also a look into your http servers error log file would reveal additional details about *what* file exactly the server tries to access internally.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arkascha, I just modified  a bit the one you suggested and now it looks like this  
RewriteRule ^/?post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/? /post.php?uid_url=$1 [L,QSA] and it's working perfectly! Thanks a gain for your support.